# Swift 2 Expected Declaration error & instance member cannot be used on view controller

Tags: ios, swift2

Here is an screenshot of the code:

[image]

The image shows a more clear view, so you better see it

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
// Inputs
    @IBOutlet weak var billField: UITextField!
//Outputs
    @IBOutlet weak var tipPercentageLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var personsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tipTotalLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tipPerPerson: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var GrandTotalLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalPerPerson: UILabel!
//Slider
    @IBOutlet weak var tipSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var personsStepper: UIStepper!
// Variables\
    var amountDouble = Double(50)
    var sliderValue = 18
    var tipPerc = 0.18
    var tip = Double(10)
    var myTip = Double(10)
    var persons = Int(1)



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        GrandTotalLabel.text = "Grand Total"
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func tipSliderChanged(sender: UISlider) {
        print("tip adjusted")

        sliderValue = Int(sender.value)
        tipPerc = Double(sliderValue) * 0.01
        tipPercentageLabel.text = "\(sliderValue)%"

    }
    @IBAction func personsStepper(sender: UIStepper) {
        print("persons adjusted")

        persons = Int(sender.value)
        personsLabel.text = "\(persons)"
    }





    let pctFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    pctFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
```

**THE FIRST ERROR IN THE LINE ABOVE THAT BEGINS WITH "pctFormatter", the error is  "EXPECTED DECLARATION"**

```
    amountDouble = (billField.text as NSString).doubleValue

    tip = amountDouble * tipPerc

    tipPercentageLabel.text = "(Int(sliderValue))%"
    tipTotalLabel.text = pctFormatter.stringFromNumber(tip)
    var result = Double(amountDouble)+Double(tip)
```

**THE SECOND ERROR IS IN THE LINE ABOVE AND THE ERROR SAYS "INSTANCE MEMBER 'amountDouble' CANNOT BE USED ON TYPE 'View Controller'**

```
    GrandTotalLabel.text = pctFormatter.stringFromNumber(tip/personsDouble)
```

**AND THE LAST ONE  IS IN THE LINE ABOVE AND SAYS EXPECTED DECLARATION**

```
    myTip = Double(tip/personsDouble)
    totalPerPerson.text = pctFormatter.stringFromNumber(result / personsDouble)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have lines of code that are not within a method. That code is just sitting inside the `class` definition and the compiler doesn't know what to make of that outside of a `func` implementation.

By the way, if your intent was to define a property that is initialized with code, you could do something like:

```
let pctFormatter: NSNumberFormatter = {
    let _formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    _formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
    return _formatter
}()
```

But the other lines of code below that `pctFormatter` were clearly intended to be put within a method, so put those with a `func` implementation.